# How to display SQL statement including host variable values in Oracle Pro*C?

Tags: sql, c, oracle, binding

In Pro*C code you can get the last executed SQL statement via [`sqlgls()` (or even `SQLStmtGetText()`)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_09err.htm#i6810).

This is useful for logging purposes - especially for dynamic statements.

But the SQL statement returned by these SQLLIB functions only inlcudes bind markers (i.e. something like `:b1`, `:b2` ...). The do not include the actual values of the used host-variables.

Thus, I have following question: How to I display the last SQL-statement including host-variable values?

Else I have to manually print all used variables after printing the string returned by `sqlgls()`. Which is not really more convenient than printing the SQL statement without using `sqlgls` at all.

For example instead of

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (:b1, :b2, :b3);
```

I want to print:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES ("hello", "world", 12);
```

(besides logging, to make it easier to copy'n'paste it into an SQL-shell - i.e. for testing)

Comment: Have you tried embeded sql on v$sqltext_with_newlines?

Comment: @JermaineXu, now I've tried it - but I don't know where I can easily get the SQL_ID from the last executed SQL-command. Also, v$sqltext_with_newlines seems to just use :bind-names as well. There is also `v$sql_bind_capture`  - but again, I need the SQL_ID.

Comment: select sql_id, prev_sql_id from v$session;

Answer (score 1):

You can use **v$sql_bind_capture** for tracing bind variable values.

v$sql_bind_capture has been introduced to report information on bind variables used by SQL cursors. This view allows the retrieval of the actual values of bind variables for a given SQL cursor. Moreover, you can get the sql text from v$sqlarea or v$sqltext or v$sqltext_with_newlines.

```
SELECT 
   a.sql_text, 
   b.name, 
   b.position, 
   b.datatype_string, 
   b.value_string 
FROM
  v$sql_bind_capture b,
  v$sqlarea          a,
  v$session          c, 
WHERE
   c.sid = (select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual)
AND
   b.sql_id = c.prev_sql_id
AND 
   b.sql_id = a.sql_id;
```

You need to try embedded sql on this statement. And get the variable you need to get the full statement. And you need a simple script to get that sql text with binded value, which I think is not more convenient than printing the bind value yourself.

Another way is to [run a 10046 level 4 trace](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4254158186083), but again you need to do some trics to support the copynpaste feature.

Comment: ok, I'll try that - this seems like an ok ansatz, because you can put it into a library and reuse that code via one function call.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the code generated by Pro*C and after a little bit of experimentation I derived the API/ABI of the used internal Oracle library functions.

Thus, I've [created the tracing library libtraceproc](https://github.com/gsauthof/traceproc) that - when pre-loaded - intercepts the relevant Oracle library function calls and pretty-prints the SQL statement including host-variable values.

The library has some runtime options, e.g. for logging to a file, output of statistics and to enable tracing before and/or after the actual Oracle call.

It also supports low-level tracing of the OCI API, i.e. you can use it for OCI/OCCI/OTL programs as well.

### Example

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtraceproc.so TRACEPROC_OPTIONS="-intercept -notime -sql" ./example/main
[..]
-- Before execution:
-- example/main.pc:274
insert into example_tbl (str,n) values ('a' ,0 ) returning n into :s5:s6  ;
insert into example_tbl (str,n) values ('b' ,1 ) returning n into :s5:s6  ;
[..]
-- After execution:
-- example/main.pc:274
insert into example_tbl (str,n) values ('a' ,0 ) returning n into 0  ;
insert into example_tbl (str,n) values ('b' ,1 ) returning n into 1  ;
[..]
```

`libtraceproc.so` is the tracing library and `main` is an example Pro*C application.

Note that no recompilation or re-linking of the Pro*C code is necessary. The tracing library is preloaded by the runtime linker.

A

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtraceproc.so TRACEPROC_OPTIONS="-help" ./example/main
```

displays the help screen of the library.